# Using SHA2-512 (CALG_SHA_512) on Windows 7 returns "Invalid Algorithm Specified"

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, sha, cryptoapi

I'm trying to use SHA2-512 on Windows 7 with CryptoAPI, however, calling `CryptCreateHash` fails with `GetLastError()`=2148073480=0x80090008, i.e. "Invalid Algorithm Specified". According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx SHA2 should be available since Windows XP SP3.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;
CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, nullptr, nullptr, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);

HCRYPTHASH hHash;
if (!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA_512, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
    DWORD err = GetLastError(); // -> 2148073480=0x80090008
}
```

Using `CALG_SHA1` instead of `CALG_SHA512` works.

Do I have to conduct some further initialization, e.g. explicitely activating SHA2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for this is, that the SHA2 algorithms are not supported by the ["Microsoft Base Cryptography Provider"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`PROV_RSA_FULL` or `PROV_RSA_SIG`).

One needs to use the ["Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`PROV_RSA_AES`) in `CryptAcquireContext`.